# How to return orElseThrow in a same condition with ifPresent using Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda

I have a Java 8 code below using ifPresent, I want in the same condition to use orElseThrow  `chatSessionStore.get(group)`  Already returns a Optional object.

```
@Override
public void forwardMessageGroup(String group, ChatMessage message) {

    chatSessionStore.get(group).ifPresent(chatProxy -> chatProxy.sendMessage(message));

}
```

Any tips?

Comment: No just to invoke the method sendMessage and if the list does not have results, the system will return a exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want is simply:

```
chatSessionStore.get(group).orElseThrow(
      () -> new RuntimeException("No group")
).sendMessage(message);
```